# ESP-IDF logging library issue

Tags: c, logging, embedded, uart, esp-idf

I am constantly facing an issue with ESP-IDF logging (or stdout printing). The code I use is pretty simple:

```
atc_send(uart_num, "ATI");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");
gpio_set_level(LED_R, 0); 
length = uart_read_bytes(uart_num, data, 1023, 20 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%.2X : %c", data[i], data[i]);
}
gpio_set_level(LED_R, 1);
```

The atc_send function is:

```
int atc_send(uart_port_t uart_num, char *command){
    command = strcat(command, "\r");
    int bytes = uart_write_bytes(uart_num, command, sizeof(command)); 
    vTaskDelay(100);
    if (bytes == -1){
        ESP_LOGE(ATC_TAG, "Error at command: %s", command);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The problem is that without any of ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something"); I writing the bytes over UART works (debugged it), the LED blinks but nothing comes on the output as a result of ESP_LOGI inside of the for-loop (after reading the response at UART). Neither does it work with print instead of ESP_LOGI, nor when I input a longer delay instead of logging "something".

Another interesting thing is that in the current situation (i.e. with a couple of ESP_LOGI(TAG, "something");) non of the "something"s is getting printed.

Also, it worked flawlessly when the contents of atc_send function were not packed in a function.

This is not the first time I faced such an issue. However before, I did not see the output from printf, and fixed it by changing it to ESP_LOGI.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
command = strcat(command, "\r");
```

invokes undefined behavior. You may not change a string literal.

You need to use a character array that has space to append the string `"\r"`.

Another problem is using the expression `sizeof(command)` in this statement

```
int bytes = uart_write_bytes(uart_num, command, sizeof(command));
```

The expression is equivalent to `sizeof( char * )`. It seems you mean `strlen( command )`.

Comment: Alright, will note that. However, I think it is unrelated to my problem, as including a random ESP_LOGI solves the issue. Also, I can check that I receive the response which contains just as many bytes as it is supposed to.

Comment: @mpio See my appended answer.

Comment: @mpio As you have it appending a string to a string _literal_ is UB--full stop. Fix the bugs.